# spark join raises "Detected cartesian product for INNER join"

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a dataframe and I want to add for each row `new_col=max(some_column0)` grouped by some other column1:

```
maxs = df0.groupBy("catalog").agg(max("row_num").alias("max_num")).withColumnRenamed("catalog", "catalogid")
df0.join(maxs, df0.catalog == maxs.catalogid).take(4)
```

And in second string I get an error:

> AnalysisException: u'Detected cartesian product for INNER join between
>   logical plans\nProject ... Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow
>   cartesian products between these relations.;'

What do I not understand: why spark finds here cartesian product?

A possible way to get this error: I save DF to Hive table, then init DF again as select from table. Or replace these 2 strings with hive query - no matter. But I don't want to save DF.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [Why does spark think this is a cross/cartesian join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477068/why-does-spark-think-this-is-a-cross-cartesian-join), it may be caused by:

> This happens because you join structures sharing the same lineage and this leads to a trivially equal condition.

As for how the cartesian product was generated? You can refer to [Identifying and Eliminating the Dreaded Cartesian Product](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3901221/Identifying-and-Eliminating-the-Dreaded-Cartesian-Product.htm).

Comment: Best to include all relevant information in your answer itself, not just in a link - links may rot, but answer text does not (hopefully)

Answer (score 3):

Try to persist the dataframes before joining them. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem with cartesian product for my join.
In order to overcome it I used aliases on DataFrames. See example

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1.alias("buildings").join(df2.alias("managers"), col("managers.distinguishedName") == col("buildings.manager"))
```

Comment: It seems it works in Pyspark with alias , but in scala dataframe API, it is not working