# Spark detected cartesian product despite the join condition is non-trivial

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.3.0 and I have two data frames.

The first one, df1, has the schema:

```
root
 |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- channel: string (nullable = false)
```

The second one, df2, has the schema:

```
root
 |-- pprChannel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ppr: integer (nullable = false)
```

I now try to do:

```
spark.sql("select a.channel as channel, a.time as time, b.ppr as ppr from df1 a inner join df2 b on a.channel = b.pprChannel")
```

But I get `Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans`.

When I try to recreate both on a Spark-Shell with `sc.parallelize` and simple Seqs, it works.

What might be wrong here?

## Followup

Here is what I get when I use `df1.join(df2, 'channel === 'pprChannel, "inner").explain(true)`:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Join Inner, (channel#124 = pprChannel#136)
:- Project [time#113L AS time#127L, channel#124]
:  +- Project [time#113L, unnamed AS channel#124]
:     +- Project [time#113L]
:        +- Project [channel#23, time#113L]
:           +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, clipDT#105L, if ((isnull(t0#93L) || isnull(t1#29L))) null else UDF(t0#93L, t1#29L) AS time#113L]
:              +- Filter (clipDT#105L >= cast(50000000 as bigint))
:                 +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, (t1#29L - t0#93L) AS clipDT#105L]
:                    +- Filter (((t0#93L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && (pt0#98 = 1)) && (pt1#82 = 2))
:                       +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98]
:                          +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, pt0#98]
:                             +- Window [lag(pt1#82, 1, 0) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS pt0#98], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L]
:                                   +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L]
:                                      +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, t0#93L]
:                                         +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#93L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                            +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82]
:                                               +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82]
:                                                  +- Filter pt1#82 IN (1,2)
:                                                     +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75, if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) AS pt1#82]
:                                                        +- Filter ((t0#70L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(dv0#75))
:                                                           +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75]
:                                                              +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75, dv0#75]
:                                                                 +- Window [lag(dv1#58, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS dv0#75], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                    +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L]
:                                                                       +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L]
:                                                                          +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, t0#70L]
:                                                                             +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#70L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58]
:                                                                                   +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58]
:                                                                                      +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49, abs(if ((isnull(v0#49) || isnull(v1#35))) null else UDF(v0#49, v1#35)) AS dv1#58]
:                                                                                         +- Filter ((t0#42L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(v0#49))
:                                                                                            +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49]
:                                                                                               +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49, v0#49]
:                                                                                                  +- Window [lag(v1#35, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS v0#49], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                                     +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                        +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                           +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                              +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#42L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                                                 +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                    +- Filter ((NOT isnull(t1#29L) && NOT isnull(v1#35)) && ((t1#29L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(v1#35)))
:                                                                                                                       +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, value#18 AS v1#35, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                          +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L AS t1#29L, value#18, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                             +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L, value#18, unnamed AS channel#23]
:                                                                                                                                +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L, UDF(_c1#11) AS value#18]
:                                                                                                                                   +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, UDF(_c0#10) AS time#14L]
:                                                                                                                                      +- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11] csv
+- Project [_1#133 AS pprChannel#136, _2#134 AS ppr#137]
   +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#133, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#134]
      +- ExternalRDD [obj#132]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
time: bigint, channel: string, pprChannel: string, ppr: int
Join Inner, (channel#124 = pprChannel#136)
:- Project [time#113L AS time#127L, channel#124]
:  +- Project [time#113L, unnamed AS channel#124]
:     +- Project [time#113L]
:        +- Project [channel#23, time#113L]
:           +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, clipDT#105L, if ((isnull(t0#93L) || isnull(t1#29L))) null else if ((isnull(t0#93L) || isnull(t1#29L))) null else UDF(t0#93L, t1#29L) AS time#113L]
:              +- Filter (clipDT#105L >= cast(50000000 as bigint))
:                 +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, (t1#29L - t0#93L) AS clipDT#105L]
:                    +- Filter (((t0#93L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && (pt0#98 = 1)) && (pt1#82 = 2))
:                       +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98]
:                          +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, pt0#98, pt0#98]
:                             +- Window [lag(pt1#82, 1, 0) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS pt0#98], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L]
:                                   +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L]
:                                      +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82, t0#93L, t0#93L]
:                                         +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#93L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                            +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82]
:                                               +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, pt1#82]
:                                                  +- Filter pt1#82 IN (1,2)
:                                                     +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75, if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) AS pt1#82]
:                                                        +- Filter ((t0#70L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(dv0#75))
:                                                           +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75]
:                                                              +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, dv0#75, dv0#75]
:                                                                 +- Window [lag(dv1#58, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS dv0#75], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                    +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L]
:                                                                       +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L]
:                                                                          +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58, t0#70L, t0#70L]
:                                                                             +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#70L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58]
:                                                                                   +- Project [channel#23, t1#29L, dv1#58]
:                                                                                      +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49, abs(if ((isnull(v0#49) || isnull(v1#35))) null else if ((isnull(v0#49) || isnull(v1#35))) null else UDF(v0#49, v1#35)) AS dv1#58]
:                                                                                         +- Filter ((t0#42L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(v0#49))
:                                                                                            +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49]
:                                                                                               +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, v0#49, v0#49]
:                                                                                                  +- Window [lag(v1#35, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS v0#49], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                                     +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                        +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                           +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23, t0#42L, t0#42L]
:                                                                                                              +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(channel#23, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#42L], [channel#23], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
:                                                                                                                 +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, v1#35, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                    +- Filter ((NOT isnull(t1#29L) && NOT isnull(v1#35)) && ((t1#29L >= cast(0 as bigint)) && NOT isnan(v1#35)))
:                                                                                                                       +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, t1#29L, value#18 AS v1#35, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                          +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L AS t1#29L, value#18, channel#23]
:                                                                                                                             +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L, value#18, unnamed AS channel#23]
:                                                                                                                                +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, time#14L, UDF(_c1#11) AS value#18]
:                                                                                                                                   +- Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, UDF(_c0#10) AS time#14L]
:                                                                                                                                      +- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11] csv
+- Project [_1#133 AS pprChannel#136, _2#134 AS ppr#137]
   +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#133, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#134]
      +- ExternalRDD [obj#132]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [UDF(t0#93L, t1#29L) AS time#127L, unnamed AS channel#124]
+- Filter ((isnotnull(pt0#98) && isnotnull(pt1#82)) && ((((t0#93L >= 0) && (pt0#98 = 1)) && (pt1#82 = 2)) && ((t1#29L - t0#93L) >= 50000000)))
   +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#93L, lag(pt1#82, 1, 0) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS pt0#98], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- Project [t1#29L, if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) AS pt1#82]
         +- Filter (((t0#70L >= 0) && NOT isnan(dv0#75)) && if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) IN (1,2))
            +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#70L, lag(dv1#58, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS dv0#75], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- Project [t1#29L, abs(UDF(v0#49, v1#35)) AS dv1#58]
                  +- Filter ((t0#42L >= 0) && NOT isnan(v0#49))
                     +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#42L, lag(v1#35, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS v0#49], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
                        +- Project [UDF(_c0#10) AS t1#29L, UDF(_c1#11) AS v1#35]
                           +- Filter ((UDF(_c0#10) >= 0) && NOT isnan(UDF(_c1#11)))
                              +- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11] csv
and
Project [_1#133 AS pprChannel#136, _2#134 AS ppr#137]
+- Filter (isnotnull(_1#133) && (unnamed = _1#133))
   +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#133, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#134]
      +- ExternalRDD [obj#132]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
== Physical Plan ==
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [UDF(t0#93L, t1#29L) AS time#127L, unnamed AS channel#124]
+- Filter ((isnotnull(pt0#98) && isnotnull(pt1#82)) && ((((t0#93L >= 0) && (pt0#98 = 1)) && (pt1#82 = 2)) && ((t1#29L - t0#93L) >= 50000000)))
   +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#93L, lag(pt1#82, 1, 0) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS pt0#98], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- Project [t1#29L, if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) AS pt1#82]
         +- Filter (((t0#70L >= 0) && NOT isnan(dv0#75)) && if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else if ((isnull(dv0#75) || isnull(dv1#58))) null else UDF(dv0#75, dv1#58) IN (1,2))
            +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#70L, lag(dv1#58, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS dv0#75], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- Project [t1#29L, abs(UDF(v0#49, v1#35)) AS dv1#58]
                  +- Filter ((t0#42L >= 0) && NOT isnan(v0#49))
                     +- Window [lag(t1#29L, 1, -1) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS t0#42L, lag(v1#35, 1, NaN) windowspecdefinition(unnamed, t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS v0#49], [unnamed], [t1#29L ASC NULLS FIRST]
                        +- Project [UDF(_c0#10) AS t1#29L, UDF(_c1#11) AS v1#35]
                           +- Filter ((UDF(_c0#10) >= 0) && NOT isnan(UDF(_c1#11)))
                              +- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11] csv
and
Project [_1#133 AS pprChannel#136, _2#134 AS ppr#137]
+- Filter (isnotnull(_1#133) && (unnamed = _1#133))
   +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#133, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#134]
      +- ExternalRDD [obj#132]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
```

Yes, `df1` is a result of a fairly complex computation, that's why it is so big. `df2` is a very small DF which always comes from a `Map` with at most about 50 to 100 entries brought to Spark with `sc.parallelize`. So I could use `crossJoin` and a `where` as a workaround. But I want to understand why Spark thinks it is a cartesian product.

## Followup 2

I am now using a different approach. Since the first DF is this huge one which is the result of a complex calculation, and the second one is always originating from a small map, I changed my algorithm to use ordinary `map` operations to achieve it:

```
val bDF2Data = sc.broadcast(df2Data)
val res =
  df1.
    as[(Long, String)].
    mapPartitions { iter =>
      val df2Data = bDF2Data.value
      iter.
        flatMap {
          case (time, channel) =>
            df2Data.get(channel).map(ppr => (time, channel, ppr))
        }
    }.
    toDF("time", "channel", "ppr").
    // More operations ...
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477068/why-does-spark-think-this-is-a-cross-cartesian-join

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't figure out what is wrong from the `explain`. I added the output of `explain` as an edit.