# Spark Dataset Joinwith Error: Join condition is missing or trivial

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to join two dataset in spark. This is what I did:

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("parquet").load("hdfs://path");
Dataset<Person> p1= data.filter("id < 200").as(Encoders.bean(Person.class)).alias("ds1");
Dataset<Person> p2= data.filter("id < 100").as(Encoders.bean(Person.class)).alias("ds2");
p1.joinWith(p2, p1.col("ds1.id").equalTo(p2.col("ds2.id")) ,"inner").show();
```

When I run the program I got this Error:

```
Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [named_struct(id, id#3L, fname, fname#1, lname, lname#4, email, email#0, gender, gender#2) AS _1#41]
+- Filter (named_struct(id, id#3L, fname, fname#1, lname, lname#4, email, email#0, gender, gender#2).id = named_struct(id, id#3L, fname, fname#1, lname, lname#4, email, email#0, gender, gender#2).id)
   +- Relation[email#0,fname#1,gender#2,id#3L,lname#4] parquet
and
Project [named_struct(id, id#39L, fname, fname#37, lname, lname#40, email, email#36, gender, gender#38) AS _2#42]
+- Relation[email#36,fname#37,gender#38,id#39L,lname#40] parquet
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Either: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these
relations, or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration
variable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;
```

What I understand from the error and look into the source code is: it think that [this is a cross join](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala) (lines 1311-1328) but it's not.

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477068/why-does-spark-think-this-is-a-cross-cartesian-join) also that said this is because structures sharing the same lineage and we should use alias and I used it and it didn't work. How Can I solve this problem?

Also there is a bug report related to this problem: [spark-25150](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without dataset prefixes ("p1.", "p2.") near "col" have to work:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
p1.joinWith(p2, col("ds1.id").equalTo(col("ds2.id")) ,"inner").show();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me How did you find out that prefixes should be deleted?

Comment: If aliases used, prefixes are not necessary.