# Spark SQL detects normal inner join as cross join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have csv data similar to the following, representing questions and answers, the latter with a reference to the question they are answering:

```
Id,Type,Parent
1,Q,
2,Q,
3,A,1
4,A,2
5,A,1
6,Q,
7,A,6
```

I'm trying to extract the answers and join them with their respective questions. This is my code:

```
val posts = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("posts.csv")
                 .as[(String, String, String)]
                 .map{case (id, kind, parent) =>
                         (id.toInt, kind, if (parent != null) parent.toInt else -1)
                     }

val questions = posts.filter(_._2 == "Q")
val answers = posts.filter(_._2 == "A")

val joined = answers.joinWith(questions, answers("_3") === questions("_1"))
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Spark complains that my `INNER JOIN` is actually a `CROSS JOIN`, but I don't see why it's saying this. The join condition is not trivial, the number of rows in the join should match the number of rows in the left operand. It's definitely not a cross product.

This is the error message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Either: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations,
or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration variable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;
```

EDIT: I checked [Why does spark think this is a cross/cartesian join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477068/why-does-spark-think-this-is-a-cross-cartesian-join) but using `alias` and `cache` as shown below didn't change the error

```
val questions = posts.filter(_._2 == "Q").alias("q").cache
val answers = posts.filter(_._2 == "A").alias("a").cache
```

Comment: @user6910411 I tried the solutions in that question, but they didn't work.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. I guess you didn't use aliases in the join: `val joined = answers.joinWith(questions, col("a._3") === col("q._1"))`

Comment: @user6910411 yes, I was using `answer("_3")` instead of `$"a._3"`. Thank you.